# How to bind a socket to multiple interfaces

Tags: sockets, interface, bind

After hours of searching on the internet, I still wasn't able to find an answer for my problem.

My task is to create a server that accepts sockets from a variable number of interfaces (given in a config file as `eth0, eth1, etc.`).

What is the easiest way to do this?
Is there any way to bind one socket to multiple interfaces? I haven't found a way to do that yet.
Or, do I have to use `INADDR_ANY` and somehow find out the interface which the packet was sent from?

Is there another way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You either [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) *one* socket to *all* interfaces with [`INADDR_ANY`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html), or create *multiple sockets* and bind each to *IP address* of the desired interface. In any case, set [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) option on the sockets.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Am I able to accept more than 65K connection limit when I use INADDR_ANY or I have to bind each IP separately for that?

Comment: @Tolga, you are probably referring to the fact that TCP port number is a 16-bit integer. That is not a limiting factor here since each given TCP connection is a 4-tuple of (src addr, src port, dest addr, dest port). You are much more likely to hit the per-process file descriptor limit on your server before reaching 65536 connections.

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov Thanks for this clear Answer. Presumably, the second option of using multiple sockets involves more programming effort, as we need to listen to and check for connections on multiple sockets (using `select` in C, perhaps). The first option seems transparent to the application so looks to me to be easier to program. Would you agree? In what circumstances would we opt for the second option?

Comment: In a case where you need different behavior on different networks you host is connected to, like a proxy or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a socket that can listen on multiple interfaces.  You'll need to know your source IPs (i.e. the addresses assigned to each interface), as well as your packets' intended destination IP address and port.  Then configure the IP_MULTICAST_IF and IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP properties for each socket.  Here's some example Python code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.bind((dst_ip, port))

for src_ip in src_ips:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton(dst_ip) + socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
```