# If I bind a socket listener to a remote IP, can I still connect to the socket from localhost?

Tags: linux, sockets

Normally, the IPC as configured in use is restricted to `localhost` (`127.0.01`) but a case has come up where a user requires the IPC connection to work additionally from a remote IP.

If, in the call to the [bind(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), I populate the relevant structure with the remote IP address, will I still be able to have other local processes connect to that port (from localhost)?

I'm not certain that this is same as [How to bind a socket to multiple interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709771/32836)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** call `bind` with the **remote** IP address.  That will not do what you think it will do.

Instead, you'll need to bind to INADDR_ANY and then drop any incoming connection that isn't from an allowed IP address.

An even better approach is to also have a firewall rule (iptables) that will block incoming connections to your listening port that isn't from the approved list of remote IPs.

When you [accept](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) the connection, check the remote address returned from that call.  Close the socket if it's not from 127.0.0.1 or the allowed remote IP address.

Ideally, you also have a secure SSL-like validation, auth token validation, or something beyond IP address to validate the authenticity of the node connecting to you.